# How to check check a key's value within an if statement

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I hope you are all well.

This is how my data looks:

```
dictionary1 = {2876: 1, 9212: 1, 953997: 1, 9205: 1, 9206: 1, 9207: 1, 9208: 1, 9209: 1, 9210: 1, 9211: 1, 6908: 1, 1532: 1, 945237: 1, 6532: 2, 6432: 4}

data1 = [[2876, 5423],[2312, 4532],[953997, 5643]...]
```

I am trying to run a statement that looks like this:

```
for y in data1:
        if y[0] in dictionary1 and dictionary1[y[0]] == 1:
            dictionary1[y[1]] = 2
```

Presumably this would create a new dataset looking like this:

```
dictionary1 = {5423: 2, 953997: 2, 2876: 1, 9212: 1, 953997: 1, 9205: 1, 9206: 1, 9207: 1, 9208: 1, 9209: 1, 9210: 1, 9211: 1, 6908: 1, 1532: 1, 945237: 1, 6532: 2, 6432: 4}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is dictionary1[y[0]] == 1 the correct way to check a key's value?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: What's wrong with the result?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehension converts the list of lists to a dictionary:

```
dict1 =  {t[0]:t[1:] for t in dictionary1}
```

Then it should be easy to do what you want:

```
for y in data1:
    if y in dict1 and dict1[y] ==1:
        dictionary1[y] = 2
```

Comment: data1 is a list of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.get(key, default)` to avoid an exception for missing values, and provide a safe default. This reduces your loop to a single condition:

```
#!python3
dictionary1 = {2876: 1, 9212: 1, 953997: 1, 9205: 1, 9206: 1, 9207: 1, 9208: 1, 9209: 1, 9210: 1, 9211: 1, 6908: 1, 1532: 1, 945237: 1, 6532: 2, 6432: 4}

data1 = [[2876, 5423],[2312, 4532],[953997, 5643]]

for x,y in data1:
    if dictionary1.get(x, 0) == 1:
        dictionary1[y] = 2

print(dictionary1)
```

You could use `dict.update(other)` to bulk-overwrite the values in dictionary1 with a one-liner dict comprehension:

```
dictcompr = {b:2 for a,b in data1 if dictionary1.get(a,0) == 1}
dictionary1.update(dictcompr)
```

And then you can combine them into one single, unholy, unmaintainable, barely-readable mess:

```
dictionary1.update({b:2 for a,b in data1 if dictionary1.get(a,0) == 1})
```

**Update:**

To delete all keys having a value of 1, you have some choices:

```
for k,v in dictionary1.items():
    if v == 1:
        del dictionary1[k]

# Versus:

d2 = dict(filter(lambda item: item[1] != 1, dictionary1.items()))
dictionary1 = d2

# or

dictionary1.clear()
dictionary1.update(d2)
```

Frankly, for your purposes the `for` loop is probably better. The `filter` approach can take the lambda as a parameter, to configure what gets filtered. Using `clear()/update()` is a win if you expect multiple references to the dictionary. That is, `A = B = dictionary1`. In this case, `clear/update` would keep the same underlying object, so the linkage still holds. (This is also true of the `for` loop - the benefit is solely for the `filter` which requires a temporary.)

Comment: This seems to be looking better than what I have! Two questions, suppose my data1 looks like this instead: [[2876, 5423, 3],[2312, 4532, 4],[953997, 5643, 5]]..., with each list having a third value I don't care about. How would I do that? 

Lastly, Is there anyway once I create dictionary[y] = 2 to delete all the instances where dictionary[x] == 1?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You could use `a,b,c` or you could use `a,b,*rest` if there are 3 or more values (*rest will pick up *all* the remaining values). As for the other, do you want to delete every key that has a value of 1, or only those identified in the data1 list?

Comment: Thank you so much! I would like to delete every key that has a value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

please try this,

```
    for y in data1:
    if y[0] in dictionary1.keys() and dictionary1.keys() == y[0]:
        dictionary1[y[1]] = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

u can simply use

```
for y in data1:
        if dictionary1.has_key(y[0]):
            dictionary1[y[1]] = 2
```

Hope this is what u r looking for .